# Pass array from VBA to Powershell

Tags: vba, powershell

I am trying to pass an array from my vba script to a powershell script. Here is what I have

```
strCommand = "powershell.exe -command Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe \"" -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NoExit -file `\""C:\ADMagic\ADMagic.ps1`\"" -FName `\""" & FName & "`\"" -middleIn `\""" & middleIn & "`\"" -LName `\""" & LName & "`\"" -Branch `\""" & Branch & "`\"" -Title `\""" & Title & "`\"" -employeeNum `\""" & employeeNum & "`\"" -company `\""" & company & "`\"" -dept `\""" & dept & "`\"" -ad `\""" & ad & "`\"" -city `\""" & city & "`\"" -state `\""" & state & "`\"" -zip `\""" & zip & "`\"" -manager `\""" & manager & "`\"" -status `\""" & status & "`\"" -groups `\""" & groups & "`\"" \ """
```

The last variable on that list is an array and whenever I try to run the script, it says there is a type mismatch on the '&' right before the 'groups' variable. I had tested it countless times without

```
" -groups `\""" & groups & "`\"
```

at the end and it worked, but now that I added this, it won't work. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: `&` is the operator for a string concatenation in VBA. You can mix in numeric variables and variable strings and literal strings and VBA will automatically convert them all into a concatenated string. The `&` operator does not accept arrays.

Comment: Ohhh, so is there another operator I should use or can I not do it at all? @Toddleson

Comment: If the array only contains strings, you can use the [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function) function. If it contains non-string elements, you'll have to manually concatenate them into a string.

Comment: Change the VBA to `& Join(groups, ";")` and have your ADMagic.ps1 script expect a `[string]` for the groups parameter. Then, in the PowerShell script split that string back to array with `$groups = $groups -split ';'`

Answer (score 0):

If the `groups` variable is an array you're going to have to run it through a `For Each` in the VBS or update your `ADMagic.ps1` to accept `groups` as an array and then run a `foreach` within the ps1 to add the user to each group.